# Adding hugepages to default boot option in grub.conf through bash script

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I want to add hugepages to grub.conf file through bash script. I can use this command

```
sed -i '0,/quiet\+/s//\0\ transparent_hugepage=never hugepages=23/' /boot/grub/grub.conf
```

However, this will add to the boot option 0 everytime. I want to check what is the default boot option (default=n) and add it to nth boot option.

Eg: grub.conf

```
default=1
title CentOS (3.12.8)
...
kernel ........ quiet

title CentOS (2.6.3)
....
kernel ........ quiet
```

Here I would want to add huge pages for CentOS (2.6.3) after quiet since its the default but

```
sed -i '0,/quiet\+/s//\0\ transparent_hugepage=never hugepages=23/' /boot/grub/grub.conf
```

will add it to CentOS (3.12.8)

Any suggestions?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this could be possible with just one `sed` command if you like really arcane programming challenges. Otherwise you could do it a bit like the following, using two `sed` commands:

```
INPUT=/boot/grub/grub.conf
POSITION=`sed -n -e '/^default=\(.*\)/\1/p' "$INPUT"`
POSITION=$(( $POSITION + 1))     # Because 'default' is 0-based
REPLACE="transparent_hugepage=never hugepages=23"
sed \
  '/^kernel /{x;s/$/Z/;/^Z\{'$POSITION'\}$/{x;s/ quiet/ quiet '$REPLACE'/p;d};x}'\
  -i "$INPUT"
```

#### Explanation

The first `sed` command extracts the position of the default, this is zero based so we need to add 1.

The second `sed` command is rather more complicated:

- For each time it finds a line starting with "kernel ", appends a 'Z' character to the hold space - i.e. `{x;s/$/Z/;`
- Thus the number of Z characters in the hold space is used to detect when the entry that needs to be edited is reached - i.e. `^/Z\{'$POSITION'\}$/` - if $POSITION is 2, this becomes `^/Z\{2\}$/` (Note the  substitution of `$POSITION` is performed by the shell)
- When this is detected, switch back, perform the actual regex replace you need to do, then delete the hold space - i.e. `{x;s/ quiet/ quiet «extra text» /p;d}`
- The above works because the `sed` command `s` always operates in pattern space
- Lastly, switch back to the pattern space and keep going - i.e. `;x}`

Take care with spaces and quotes, etc.